# How to refer same temporary directory in two different functions

Tags: python, function, temporary-files, temporary-directory

How can I refer the same temporary directory in two different function. I need to access the files that are decompressed in move_source_to_dest as an input to the function df_to_csv in the pd.read_csv statement. I've tried few changes but nothing is working out. Please help.

```
def move_source_to_dest(key, src_session):

    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:

        try:
            print("downloading {}/{}".format(s3_src_bucket, key))
            src_session.client('s3').download_file(Bucket=s3_src_bucket, Key=key,
                                               Filename=os.path.join(tempdir, os.path.basename(key)))

            #Command to decompress the files
            command = "bzip2 -dk " + os.path.join(tempdir, os.path.basename(key))
            subprocess.call(command,shell = True)


        except Exception as e:
            print("exception handling {}/{}".format(s3_src_bucket, key))
            raise e
def df_to_csv(key, src_session):
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
        try:
            #Reading all the columns names from the file "ambs_ambi_ColumnsNames.txt"
            with open('./shakenbake_ds/ambs_ambi_ColumnsNames.txt') as f:
                clist= f.read().splitlines()

                #file = open('ambs_ambi_ColumnsNames.txt','r')
                #clist=file.readlines()

            Filename=os.path.join(tempdir, os.path.basename(key[:-4]))
            Fileout=os.path.join(tempdir, os.path.basename(key[:-4])) + "-out.csv" 

            with open('./shakenbake_ds/ambs_ambi_OutColumnsNames.txt') as o:
                outcols= o.read().splitlines()
                #file = open('ambs_ambi_OutColumnsNames.txt','r')
                #outcols=file.readlines()
                #global Filename
            c=0
            for chunk in pd.read_csv(Filename, sep="\x01", names=clist ,iterator=True, chunksize=300000):
```

Comment: Pass the temporary directory as a parameter to both functions.

Comment: You should probably pass `tempdir` as a parameter to `run` and `run1`. Stackoverflow isn't the best place to debug code, especially if you don't describe why you know it's not working. See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Pass the temporary directory as a parameter to both functions:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
    move_source_to_dest(key, src_session, tempdir)
    df_to_csv(key, src_session, tempdir)
```

Answer (score 1):

One common way to share state between functions is to pass that state as an argument to those functions.

For example,

```
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
    move_source_to_dest(tempdir, ...)
    df_to_csv(tempdir, ...)
```

with `move_source_to_dest` and `df_to_csv` re-defined like:

```
def move_source_to_dest(tempdir, key, src_session):
    # no additional tempdir created here
    # ...

def df_to_csv(key, src_session):
    # no additional tempdir created here
    # ...
```